# Why does absorbed dose increase with increasing tube potential in computed tomography?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, x-rays, medical-physics

In X-ray [radiography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectional_radiography) it is a common technique to reduce patient absorbed dose by increasing the X-ray tube potential (kVp) while keeping the detector exposure constant by decreasing the tube current-time product (mAs). The increase in photon energy means less attenuation as the mass attenuation coefficient is highly energy dependent. Less attenuation leads to less absorbed dose by the patient.

In [Computed Tomography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CT_scan) (CT), however, dose reduction is usually achieved by decreasing tube potential and using a lower average photon energy. I could not find a clear explanation why the logic we use to explain the dose reduction method in radiography does not work for CT. What am I missing?

Comment: Can some good linked sources (journal articles, books, websites) be provided for the claim that CT "dose reduction is usually achieved by decreasing tube potential"?

Answer (score 0):

To the extent that the question's assumption is true, the difference is likely due the relative changes in [photo-electric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect) and [Compton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering) absorption at the higher tube voltages needed for whole body CT scans.  CT scans also sometimes used contrast agents that provide better images at lower tube potentials.

In general, however, optimizing clinical usefulness for any x-ray scan while minimizing dose depends on who and what is being imaged and involves the shape of the x-ray spectrum, the tube current, the length of the exposure, the collimation of the beam, and the hardware and software capabilities of the imaging system.
Nevertheless, let's first review why increased tube potential sometimes reduces patient dose.

**Dose vs Tube potential**

If we ignore [characteristic radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_X-ray), then the [bremsstrahlung x-ray spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_tube#Physics) roughly falls off linearly with energy.  As shown in the figure, the spectrum is roughly [triangular in shape](http://www.sprawls.org/ppmi2/XRAYPRO/#Effect%20of%20KV) and the total x-ray flux increases roughly with the square of the maximum photon energy set by the tube potential $V$.
[image: Bremsstrahlung x-ray spectra for tube voltages of 50, 75, 100, and 125 KV.]

If most of these x-rays are absorbed by the patient, the dose to the patient scales as
$$Dose \propto V^2$$

**Image quality vs Tube potential**

To make an x-ray image, some - but not all - the x-rays must penetrate through the subject to be detected.
At lower x-ray energies, their absorption is dominated by the [photo-electric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect#Competing_processes_and_photoemission_cross_section) and the x-ray absorption length increases roughly with the cube of the photon energy $E$.
At higher energies, [Compton scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering) becomes important and the energy dependence flattens out.
[image: Plots of x-ray attenuation vs energy for human tissue and bone]

Combining the $V^2$ flux and $V^3$ attenuation length dependences, we expect that at lower energies the number of x-ray photons $N$ reaching the film/detector will depend roughly on the fifth power of the tube potential:
$$N\sim V^5$$

This is the physics origin of the ["15% rule"](https://howradiologyworks.com/15percentrule/) that says that increasing the tube potential by 15% and reducing the x-ray tube current by a factor of 2 gives the same number of photons reaching the detector but reduces the patient dose by about =30% (since $1.15^2/2 \sim 0.7$).

The above description is somewhat idealized. For example, modern CT machines typically include metal filters that block much of the low energy spectrum which does not penetrate to the detector but which contributes most of the dose to the patient.  This increases the x-ray flux dependence on tube potential.

**CT Radiography**

Any radiographic scan imaging through the whole body will need to operate at tube potentials around or above 100 KV to produce high-energy x-rays with sufficient penetration.
The absorption length for such high-energy x-rays flattens out which means the number of x-rays reaching the detector starts moving from a $V^5$ dependence towards a $V^2$dependence, where dose and image quality are linearly correlated.
Since the modern x-ray detectors and image processing software used in CT scans have much greater dynamic range than traditional film, one may not need as high a voltage to get enough penetrating photons to produce an image with sufficient contrast for clinical use.

One major application of CT scans where lower potential is often best is for imaging vascular structures and organs, since [iodine contrast agents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iodinated_contrast) are often injected into the patient prior to the scan. Iodine [has increased X-ray attenuation at lower tube potential than high potential](https://doi.org/10.2217/iim.09.5), so lower tube potentials may give better CT contrast with reduced patient dose.  This may not work for large patients, however, where higher energy x-rays are needed to sufficiently penetrate the patient to avoid low-quality noisy images.